# PowerBI - filter for selected date - 4 weeks

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, dax, datefilter

I've got a problem I've had for a while now and can't crack, so seeking some advice.

I have a table with a column of dates with the week beginning date. On my report page I have a slicer that displays the date of this column, and filters various visuals on the page.

In another table, I have a column with the week number, and at the moment I have a graph that displays data for 4 filtered 'Week numbers' - this is the last 4 weeks from today's date. To achieve this, I've created a new calculated column with the following code, and filtered the graph to 'yes':

```
last4weeks = IF(
    AND(
        DATEDIFF([Week Beginning],TODAY(),WEEK) > 0,
        DATEDIFF([Week Beginning],TODAY(),WEEK) <= 4
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

What I would like to do, is to apply a similar filter, but one that takes the selected value from the slicer I have on the page (the 'Week Beginning' date) and filter the last 4 'Week Numbers' from that selected date. There is already a relationship between the two tables with a Date column.

I have tried:

```
last4weeks = 
IF(
    AND(
        DATEDIFF('Firstbeat Data Sheet'[Week Beginning], SELECTEDVALUE('Firstbeat Data Sheet'[Week Beginning]), WEEK) > 0,
        DATEDIFF('Firstbeat Data Sheet'[Week Beginning], SELECTEDVALUE('Firstbeat Data Sheet'[Week Beginning]), WEEK) <= 4
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

The desired outcome is to have a filter that will say "Yes" if the dates fall within 4 weeks prior to the date on the page slicer, and "No" if not.

Any help much appreciated (example below)

[PBI Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSOLz.png)

Comment: This will need to be done as a measure, since Calculated Columns are calculated once during dataset refresh. Could you share a sample pbix?

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your response. Yeah I thought that would be the case, but tried several ways with no luck. I've added a link at the bottom to an example image - I can't share the pbix as everything is highly sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a relationship between Table1 and Table2, then you could try:

```
last4weeks = 
  var fDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[Week Beginning], MAX('Table1'[Week Beginning]))
  var wkDiff = DATEDIFF(MIN('Table2'[Week Beginning]), fDate, WEEK)
  return IF(1 <= wkDiff && wkDiff <= 4, "Yes", "No")
```

And if you do have a relationship then:

```
last4weeks = 
  var fDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[Week Beginning], MAX('Table1'[Week Beginning]))
  var wkDiff =
    CALCULATE(
      DATEDIFF(MIN('Table2'[Week Beginning]), fDate, WEEK),
      ALL('Table1')
    )
  return IF(1 <= wkDiff && wkDiff <= 4, "Yes", "No")
```

Sample PBIX for demo: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtpcKzRsDrY1o7YwCp1EMbgH6H5RqA?e=VjPXqv

Comment: Hi Sam, I do have a relationship between the two tables already, to filter other data.  This just returns "No" for everything unfortunately. When I use the calc column using the TODAY function above as a filter, I get the option of Yes or No, with this (and any other measure I've tried), I just get "No" as an option.

Comment: Updated answer to include if a relationship does exist (2nd option)

Comment: No still not getting anything other than "No"

Comment: It is working on my side - can you share the PBIX? Or share your dax for `last4weeks` and confirm the relationship.

Comment: Sorry I can't share the file as it's sensitive data, but the relationship is many to one, single cross filter direction from Table 1 to Table 2, from the Dates column (Week Beginning col calculated from the Dates column).

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using Table1 for your slicer, and Table2 as your chart axis?

Comment: Added sample PBIX for demo in the answer above. (It doesn't take much to provide a sample pbix for us to help you.)

Comment: Hi Sam - thanks I've got this working now with your above code. I think it was because the leg load data was a Weekly Total column, already calculated. You've used a measure here instead which works. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Splendid, please help mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of all.